# Losing bytes from a byte[] when sent in a HttpResponseMessage and interpreted in an angular promise

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've come across a problem in a transfer of information over the wire that is confusing me.

I have a WebAPI endpoint. When called it asks for a particular file and then serves it as a bytearraycontent

```
public class SampleType
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("document")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BuildDocumentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, SampleType candidateInput)
{
    var document = await _applicationService.GetByIdAsync(candidateInput.Id);
    var generatedDocument = new CandidatePdfDocumentBuilder().BuildDocument(document, candidateInput.Url);

    var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(generatedDocument);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

    return response;
}
```

I can see that the document build here has a size of, in my test case, 53993 bytes. It is a PDF document. I have written the document to disk in my test case, and the size of the file on disk agrees with the number bytes in my `generatedDocument`.

I have an angular architecture that communicates with this.

An infrastructure service that wraps `$http`

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var httpModelService = function ($http) {

        this.postTo = function (endpoint, model) {
            return $http.post(endpoint, model);
        }
    };

    var app = angular.module("myApplicationName");
    app.service("httpModelService", httpModelService);
}());
```

A service

```
this.buildDocument = function (documentID) {
    return httpModelService.postTo('release-protocol/document', { url: $location.absUrl(), id: documentID });
};
```

A controller

```
releaseProtocolService.buildDocument($scope.document.id).
    then(function(response) {
        var dataSize = response.data.length;
            saveData(response.data, $scope.document.documentName + '.pdf');
        });
```

I can see, however, that if I examine the length of response.data, in my case this is a smaller number of bytes - 52137 in my case.

With all of this background out of the way, what could be causing me to have fewer bytes available in my `response.data`?

Comment: Weird.. Maybe you can transfer it by converting it to base64 first, and then unpack the bytes on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Response.data.length gives you the character length not necessarily the byte size.